# Usage of strings in protobuf-C

Tags: c, linux, protocol-buffers

Iam new to use protobuf. Am using protobuf library in Linux-C.

Is there any example for setting **optional and required *string*** to my message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [protobuf front page](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) has an example of a `.proto`-file containing:

```
required string name = 2;
optional string email = 3;
```

So that doesn't seem to be very complicated. There doesn't seem to be an "official" C API on those pages, and you didn't provide a link to the one you're using so it's hard to say more.

Comment: For setting optional integer value, noticed a function _has. And integer value shall be assigned by using "=" sign. In same way, wanted sample code for setting value for name and email.

Comment: In protobuff front page, example function for c++ has set_*, which is used for setting name and email, But didn't find such functions in C.